# AWS: Enabled logging on RDS Aurora, but general_log and slow_log tables are empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am working on AWS system and created RDS Aurora cluster with a custom DBClusterParameterGroup (everything deployed viac CloudFormation). Parameter group is created and correctly assigned to the cluster. It looks like this (it has logging enabled to the table)

```
> RDSDBClusterParameterGroup: 
>       Properties: 
>         Description: "Parameter Group with enabled logging"
>         Family: aurora5.6
>         Parameters: 
>           slow_query_log: 1
>           general_log: 1
>           log_output: TABLE
>           long_query_time: 2
>       Type: "AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup"
```

But the problem is - even though I already created some DBs and tables on the cluster, once I query *mysql.general_log*, I see it is empty. Why is it so? I assumed it tracked all statements ran over the cluster, does someone have an idea why it is completely empty. I can query and see content of other mysql tables. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't log to a table, it logs to cloudwatch

Comment: "log_output. This setting was formerly only in the DB instance parameter group. This setting has a default value of FILE. You can't change this value." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html

Comment: Thank you, didnt notice that I cant chance log_output if Aurora is serverless

Answer (score 0):

As jordanm mentioned in comments - one can not change value of log_output if Aurora is serverless, it has the default value FILE.